# Rewrite a Views Field to get rid of accents. I need roman alphabet characters for a csv export

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I'm using [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to generate CSV files for end-users to use and then re-upload using Feeds. I need Vietnamese characters like `â ỏ ể` to be converted to `a o e` before export as these are in users' names.

I tried `utf8_decode` in Views Data Export settings but it doesn't work for all characters and <strike>even then, changing Feeds to use `ISO-8859-1` still results in a "This isn't a UTF-8 file" error.</strike>

It seems that changing a setting in Excel can fix this but that isn't an option for me for usability reasons. I'm not the one who will be using these CSV files so I need these names to be exported properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting "Character encoding conversion" in the data export view's CSV file settings to:

`ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT`

should accomplish what you're attempting. That will convert the names to the ISO-8859-1 character set, with transliteration of characters not included in the set to something that appears similar.

Comment: Thanks, this is a big improvement. However, there are still a few characters that come out messy.. Looking around the net, it seems that Vietnamese has too many characters for ISO-8859-1 or something like that. But it's close enough so thanks!